# Error :- -[UIButton setValue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I had created 
1)customcell in the table and there is 1 button and 1 slider inside the cell.

```
           NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];

        if (obj_TextCell == nil) {                
                        obj_TextCell = [[[TextCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

           }
    UIButton* Btn_music=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130,180, 50,50)];

                if (indexPath.row==play_tg)
                {
                     [Btn_music setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pausemusic.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                }else
                {
                    [Btn_music setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playmusic.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }             

              [Btn_music addTarget:self action:@selector(playAudio:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
              Btn_music.tag = indexPath.row;
              [obj_TextMusicCell.contentView addSubview:Btn_music];
              [background bringSubviewToFront:Btn_music];
 UISlider *progress = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180,195,320,10)];
            [progress setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            progress.minimumValue = 0.0;
            progress.maximumValue=1.0;
            progress.continuous = YES;
            progress.value = 0.0;
            progress.tag=indexPath.row+1;
            NSLog(@"tag for slider========>%d",progress.tag);
            //[progress setTag:indexPath.row];
            [progress addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [obj_TextMusicCell.contentView addSubview:progress];
```

2)The IBACTION event of the button i had fetch the cell.and had called the method in which the slider moves.

```
-(IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *Btn_music=sender;    

    cell_Access = (TextMusicCell *)[tbl_tellTale viewWithTag:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tbl_tellTale indexPathForCell:cell_Access];
     NSLog(@"cellindex==>%d",indexPath.row); 
if ( timer==nil)
        {
          timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(SongProgress) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
           [timer fire];
        }

}
```

3)The method in the slider has :-

```
-(IBAction)SongProgress
{

   UISlider* progress = (UISlider *)[cell_Access viewWithTag:1];
}
```

4)It works perfectly.But when i scroll the table view or at some time the application get crashed and give the below error:-

```
-[UIButton setValue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x96f9660
2013-02-20 19:54:21.008 shc[3776:19d03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton setValue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x96f9660'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3dba012 0x2777e7e 0x3e454bd 0x3da9bbc 0x3da994e 0x108d1b 0x21c0b90 0x3d79376 0x3d78e06 0x3d60a82 0x3d5ff44 0x3d5fe1b 0x33de7e3 0x33de668 0x16bf65c 0x2cb6 0x2be5 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

-[UIButton setValue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You are using same tag value for UIBUTTON* btn_music as well as UISlider *progress, therefore UISlider *progress getting UIBUTTON instance
use different tag values for both like if you using 1 to 200 tag value for UIBUTTON then use 201 plus values for UISlider *progress

Answer (score -1):

You are probably doing the first part in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, if so, you are creating new `UIButtons` and `UISliders` every time the `UITableView`needs to render that cell...

You should add properties for `UIButton` and `UISlider` and check if they are initialized or not...

EDIT:

Ok, if you have the properties `Btn_music` and `progress` defined in your custom UITableViewCell, you should synthesize them and then initialize them like this:

```
// If the Button is not yet initialized, then do it
if(obj_TextMusicCell.Btn_music == nil)
{
    // Here you should do the initialization code that only have to be done the first time
    obj_TextMusicCell.Btn_music=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130,180, 50,50)];
    obj_TextMusicCell.Btn_music.tag = indexPath.row;
    [obj_TextMusicCell.contentView addSubview:Btn_music];
}

// Now it already exists, just update it...
if(indexPath.row==play_tg)
{
    [obj_TextMusicCell.Btn_music setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pausemusic.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else
{
    [obj_TextMusicCell.Btn_music setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playmusic.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Follow the same idea with the `UISlider` and you got it...

Comment: I had UIButton* Btn_music=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130,180, 50,50)]; and for slider:-             UISlider *progress = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180,195,320,10)];
 is it not enough?Please guide me..Thanks for the answer.

Comment: apascua Thanks for the Reply.But by declaring the Btn_music in .h file how this will help me to solve the issue.how does it matter if i declare the button in .h file or .m file

Comment: You need a reference so that you don't init it again and again, and you need that reference in the Cell context, so, if you want to have access from the UITableViewController, it must be defined in your header file... Hope you can solve it...